# Android File To Base64 using streaming sometimes missed 2 bytes

Tags: java, android, file, base64

i am writing to ask for the proper solution for solving the following difficulties:

I am required to encode the file in Base64 format, and there is no way for me to make the file small, as a result, i will surely suffered from OutOfMemory Exception, that why i used Streaming approach for solving it. 
After the file is encoded, i have decoded it immediately by code and also online-tools. The decoded content was found missing 2 bytes at the end of the file sometimes, but not always. It did affected further processing to the file.

Hope someone could help and may be caused by an idiot mistake. Still thanks.

Here is the Code:

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path + ".txt");
//this is for printing out the base64 content
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(path);

System.out.println("File Size:" + path.getTotalSpace());

ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Base64OutputStream base64out = new Base64OutputStream(os,Base64.NO_WRAP);

byte[] buffer = new byte[3 * 512];
int len = 0;
while ((len = fin.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
    base64out.write(buffer, 0, len);
}

System.out.println("Encoded Size:" + os.size());

String result = new String(os.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");

fout.write(os.toByteArray());
fout.close();
base64out.close();
os.close();
fin.close();

return result;
```

Comment: You might want to flush() your output stream before closing it.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper do you mean adding <var>.flush() before each output stream before closing it?
Therefore it will be:
fout.flush();
fout.close();
base64out.flush();
base64out.close();
os.flush();
os.close();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution that works in the case of using Base64OutputStream. I will explain some of them after code:

Here is the Code:

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path + ".txt");
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(path);

System.out.println("File Size:" + path.length());

ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Base64OutputStream base64out = new Base64OutputStream(os,Base64.NO_WRAP);

byte[] buffer = new byte[3 * 512];
int len = 0;
while ((len = fin.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
    base64out.write(buffer, 0, len);
}

System.out.println("Encoded Size:" + os.size());

base64out.flush();
base64out.close();//this did the tricks. Please see explanation.

String result = new String(os.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");      

fout.write(os.toByteArray());
fout.flush();
fout.close();
os.close();
fin.close();

return result;
```

Actually, after using the suggestion from Dawnkeeper by added flush(), i have moved one line of code only.
The tricks is did in the base64out.close() before processing any data. As closing the Base64OutputStream might write Ending Padding of Base64 to the Output.
I got my idea from [org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.util.Base64OutputStream](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-1_2/trinidad-api/apidocs/org/apache/myfaces/trinidad/util/Base64OutputStream.html) close() method. That's why i tried.

It might seems strange closing the OutputStream before data processing, but it only close Base64OutputStream but not ByteArrayOutputStream at the same time in this case. Therefore, the data could still retrieve from ByteArrayOutputStream.

Thanks Dawnkeeper efforts, and hope this question could helps other suffered in OutOfMemory Exception.

Comment: Blocks of code are not considered solutions, you should describe how it solves your problem.

Comment: i have done those explanation in the question. This solution is just intentioned to close the topic

Comment: You should not provide answers within questions. Instead copy the explanation from the question to the answer and remove the answer from the question please.

Answer (score 0):

Your streams should be flushed before using them for other operations and before closing them:

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path + ".txt");
//this is for printing out the base64 content
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(path);
System.out.println("File Size:" + path.length());   // path.getTotalSpace() is the filesystem size
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Base64OutputStream base64out = new Base64OutputStream(os,Base64.NO_WRAP);

byte[] buffer = new byte[3 * 512];
int len = 0;
while ((len = fin.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
    base64out.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
System.out.println("Encoded Size:" + os.size());

base64out.write(System.lineSeparator().getBytes());   
base64out.flush();  // to be sure that everything is in the byte array
String result = new String(os.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
fout.write(os.toByteArray());
fout.flush();  // make sure everything is written
fout.close();
base64out.close();
os.close();
fin.close();

System.out.println("new File Size:" + new File(path + ".txt").length()); // prints out the size of the finished file

return result;
```

Comment: I tried the code by running it in circles converting a 2MB file over and over. Never got a size difference. Also I changed the code to fix a wrong length used for output.

Comment: Yup,i saw it, but it doesn't help. I have tried your code, but still got size difference. Besides, as i have mentioned, it occur sometimes only,but not always. I have tried your answer for 10 different files,but only 5 succeed.

Comment: Is it always the same files that fail? If yes: whats the difference to the successful ones?

Comment: It seems that the Stream needs a line break at the end to work properly. I changed the code to work with that. You will have to test if it influences the previously working files. If it does you have to detect a line feed ad the files end and add it if needed. And finally are you sure that `Base64.NO_WRAP` is named and used correctly as it turns encoding on and off?

Comment: It is not always the same files that fail, but randomly and can't specify it. Again, Thanks for your suggestion and i have finally found the solution without coding the line separator at the end. Besides, i am quite sure for Base64.NO_WRAP is used correctly, as it should omit the line terminator for avoiding the line is too long, but i could only allow it without line terminator. i will update my question after removing some dummy code. Thanks again.