# Base64 encoding omits final 2 bytes

Tags: android, base64

This code is going to encode a bitmap to Base64. For debugging purposes I've written also few lines to put all the data into ordinary files. Problem is that files are different:
File saved directly from bitmap:

```
DB 5A C4 80 00 00
```

file saved from decoded b64 data:

```
DB 5A C4 80
```

So after encode/decode 2 bytes MIA The right file is the first one as it can be easily opened by chrome, image viewers etc. My code:

```
Bitmap exportedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(EXPORTED_IMAGE_SIZE, EXPORTED_IMAGE_SIZE, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(exportedBitmap);
float imageViewRatio = EXPORTED_IMAGE_SIZE / (float) getWidth();

canvas.save();
canvas.scale(imageViewRatio, imageViewRatio);
drawPhoto(canvas, mScale);
canvas.restore();



ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(512000);
Base64OutputStream base64OutputStream = new Base64OutputStream(outStream, Base64.DEFAULT);

String timeString = new Date().toString();
File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "origin"+ timeString +".webp");
if (!outputFile.exists())
{
    outputFile.delete();
}
outputFile.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
TeeOutputStream teeOutputStream = new TeeOutputStream(base64OutputStream, fileOutputStream);



exportedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 85, teeOutputStream);

getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(outputFile)));

exportedBitmap.recycle();
teeOutputStream.flush();
String outString = outStream.toString();
teeOutputStream.close();


decodeDataToFile(timeString, outString);
```

And the save decoded file method (just for reference - result of this is wrong also on different platform back end service):

```
private void decodeDataToFile(String pTimeString, String pOutString) throws IOException
{
    File decodedFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "processed" + pTimeString + ".webp");
    decodedFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream decodedFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(decodedFile);
    decodedFileOutputStream.write(Base64.decode(pOutString, Base64.DEFAULT));

    decodedFileOutputStream.flush();
    decodedFileOutputStream.close();
    getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(decodedFile)));
}
```

Comment: The provided code shows only one variant of saving the file, but the question implies there is another variant which produces different result. Where is this second variant?

Comment: Yes, you are right, added missing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution - here is the answear: [Android File To Base64 using streaming sometimes missed 2 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798745/android-file-to-base64-using-streaming-sometimes-missed-2-bytes)

In short - there is a need for `base64OutputStream.close();` before doing anything more with encoded `byte[] / String`