# OOM on generating base64 of Image bitmap

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-imageview, android-glide

I am using glide to display image into imageView. I know glide is enough smart to display large size of images. I need to do one additional thing after user select image from device gallery.

I need to generate base64 String which will sent to server.

Issue is if user select 33 MB image file and if I try to create base64 string from bitmap, its throws OOM.

Is there any way get base64 String of bitmap without OOM.

Applying Transform will reduce image size as well as quality. I need to send actual image.

Comment: I think that it is impossible to process so large image (to base64 string). You can try to split image to parts, and send them separately, but I'm not sure that it will work.

Comment: Why do u have to send image in `Base64` format to your server. Can u try to send it as attachment stream

Comment: One of possible solution is to use NDK to create and send data to server - when you work with C++ you havent heap restriction and could use almost all memory of device. But the best solutions is to split image to small parts and send one by one. or to use stream to upload bytes from file to server, not string

Answer (score 1):

To prevent OOM you can:

1) Trim original image to sufficient size and then create Base64

2)Ask backend developer to create stream request to send file entirely

3) [Use Base64 with I/O streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24903555/3559673)